# How to subtract 1 day 16 hours from datetime in PHP

Tags: php, strtotime

I'm trying subtracting Day and Hour from given date time example:

```
$schedule_date_time = '2016-02-29 08:30 PM';
echo date( "Y-m-d h:i a", strtotime("-1 day 16 hours", strtotime($schedule_date_time)) );
```

It gives me following result: **2016-02-29 12:30 pm**

Which is not correct...

But If I do this  :

```
$schedule_date_time = '2016-02-29 08:30 PM';
    echo date( "Y-m-d h:i a", strtotime("-1 day -16 hours", strtotime($schedule_date_time)) );
```

It gives me following result: **2016-02-28 04:30 am**

which is correct but is not possible for me to identify and put minus sign in string just before the integer.

Comment: Convert days to hours then, so you will subtract 40 hours directly.

Comment: @slax0r not all days are 24 hours long.

Comment: Have you tried subtracting 40 hours instead of 1 day, 16 hours?  Also, unless you're using a universal timezone (such as UTC/GMT/Zulu) how do you propose to take daylight savings into account?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`date_sub`](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.sub.php)/`DateTime::sub`.

```
$date = date_create("2016-02-29 08:30 PM") ;
date_sub($date, date_interval_create_from_date_string('1 day 16 hours'));
echo date_format($date, 'Y-m-d h:i a'); // 2016-02-28 04:30 am
```

If you want add an amount of time instead of subtracts it, use `date_add` instead.

Answer (score 4):

The [DateTime](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) object is so powerful in PHP:

```
$dateTimeObj = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', '2016-04-04 15:20:00');
$dateTimeObj->modify('-1 day');
$dateTimeObj->modify('-16 hours');
echo $dateTimeObj->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

It's very simple to use and very maintainable for future code-reviewers.

Comment: Or just $dateTimeObj->modify ("-40 hours").  Or you could use intervals.

Comment: @GordonM because of [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daylight_saving_time). 40 hours might not always be 1 day and 16 hours.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `DateTime::sub` class method along with `DateInterval` class like as

```
$date2 = new DateTime('2016-02-29 08:30 PM');
$date2->sub(new DateInterval('P1DT16H'));
echo $date2->format("Y-m-d H:i:s");
```